# How do I model a dependent variable that is a proportion?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

**Problem**
I am trying to test gender differences in the risk propensity of investors related to specific kind of stocks. More specifically, I want to the test the hypothesis predicting that female investors would be less risk averse than male investors.

**Data**
For each stock in my dataset, I have `riskiness` of the stock (continuous variable), along with `IDs` of individuals who have invested in the stock as well as their `gender`. Each stock can attract multiple investors and all individuals could potentially invest in multiple stocks.

**Model**
My thought was to have `proportion of female investors` for a stock as a dependent variable and `riskiness` as a predictor. A positive and significant coefficient of `riskiness` would indicate support for the hypothesis.

**Question**
 1. Is this a correct specification of model?
 2. If so, what type of regression should I use?
 3. How do I control for random effects of investors in a mixed model?
 3. How do I implement this is in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would treat `riskiness` as a continuous outcome and see if there are differences in the average riskiness between males and females. Moreover, it seems that you have a crossed design. Hence, I would start with a model of the form (using function `lmer()` from the R package **lme4**):

```
fm <- lmer(riskiness ~ gender + (1 | ID) + (1 | stock), data = your_data)
```

The coefficient for `gender` will denote the difference in the average `riskiness` between males and females.

In addition, you could also consider whether the differences you may see between males and females are attributed to other factors, e.g., age, education, etc. In this case, you may want to also control for these variables in your model.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I modeled initially. I was asked to try the approach mentioned in the question. I guess the model with proportion of female investors as DV cannot account for crossed design in any way.

Comment: could I also model this with investor gender as outcome variable and use binary logistic regression with riskiness as predictor, and ID and stock as random effects? The reason I ask is this helps me make statement like "riskier projects are more likely to attract female investors than male investors"

Comment: I think you can make a similar statement from the model I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

A popular way to regress proportions to variables is to use the logistic regression.

Before fitting a model, you can also go non parametric and just plot the proportion of investors against the quantiles of riskiness.

Comment: Thank you. Please suggestion some ways to get the required plots.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using this as your dependent variable, estimate a censored regression, since the dependent variable is bound on the interval [0,1].

As mentioned in the comment above, logistic regression would be interesting, if you have investor-specific (beyond gender). A dummy variable for gender would allow you to look at an individual's probability of investing (though you may not have adequate data for this. It's hard to tell from your description.

Other interesting questions could come from looking at the size of investments, rather than measuring investments as a binary variable. By looking at the proportion of investors, you aren't distinguishing between someone investing one dollar and someone else investing one million dollars.

Comment: Thank you, I unfortunately do not have the size of investment information.

Comment: Please suggest how I could control for nested nature of investors in censored or logistic regression.

Comment: Well it was worth mentioning. If that's all the data you have, the censored regression is your best bet. If you don't have any individual characteristics, logistic regression would be missing a lot of important covariates. For censored regression, what nesting are you referring to? The fact that a single investor may invest in multiple stocks?

Also, I caution against the specification above. How would you measure an individual's 'riskiness' if they invested in multiple stocks? I think the dependent variable has a misleading interpretation as written.